# “Slept off”: correct or incorrect?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have been using *slept off* to mean that I fell asleep. For example,

> I slept off early yesterday.

Is that used  correctly?

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing two common English expressions:

I went to bed at 11pm, and soon dropped off (to sleep).

He had had too much to drink at the party; he had to take a taxi to his London flat, where he slept off the effects of the claret and whisky.

You need 'drop(ped) off'.

Comment: Reference: [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sleep?q=sleep+off#sleep__50)

Comment: Also, *doze off*, *nod off* and *drift off*, though the first two in particular imply that you weren't intending to fall asleep and likely didn't stay asleep very long.